# How to send the reports through E-mail and Windows file simultaneously in SQL server 2008 report services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using the SQL server 2008.

The scenario is:
We have about two hundred reports to generate daily, and it need plenty of time to query in DB and refine the data. We hope the reports can be sent from e-mail and saved at the windows file system at the same time. So the method need two different subscription for the two ways of delivery is not acceptable.

Wondering if we can make it by customizing the subscription directly or write some dll to enhance it(like allow us selecting a new customized delivery when edit the subscription). Could u pls give me some ideas on it? If not, we have to write a new program to do it..but it needs effort..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to [cache the reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx) so that they run quickly the second time.

Another option would be to put the files in a Windows file share and use [SSIS SendMail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to pick up the files and email them out.

One more option is to write your own report runner that runs the reports and deals with them as you want. I was unsatified with the Reporting Services scheduler options and did it this way. It isn't as hard as you might think and [Microsoft has some code that will get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: thx, I think that's enough for me :)